# How to get Kinect's serial number with OPENNI

Tags: c++, kinect, openni, openi-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear friends,

I am new in "openni". I want to get my Kinect's serial number that I can use this to relate the "openni_tracker" package to each kinect to have a multi skeleton tracking of a ONE human body.

I know already that we could have the Serial Number in Linux by :

- List item lsusb -v

But I wanted to get this number by openni c++, then I tried this answer of this question :

- List item http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988090/how-can-i-get-the-kinect-serial-number-with-openni

But it still didnt work for me. I did not achieve to print my Serial or use it.

Can you please help me?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/179953/how-to-get-kinect%27s-serial-number-with-openni/) by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 264 on 2014-06-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[openni_camera](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_camera) prints the serial number and uses it to load the right camera parameters, too.

This should help: https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni_camera/blob/hydro-devel/src/nodelets/driver.cpp#L237

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2014-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1